# Stackdeck - View multiple SE sites on the same screen

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: preview]

### About

Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange sites allow you to view questions and filter tags as you please, but only within one site. Considering there is a lot of overlap in certain audiences for certain sites (SO, Software Engineering, Server Fault, DBA, Gamedev, etc etc etc) it would certainly (hopefully!) be useful to some if they could see multiple sites at once. Much like TweetDeck allows users to see multiple "lanes" of tweets, Stackdeck creates multiple lanes (5 in a row with unlimited vertical scrolling) to read.

#### License

Haven't picked a license yet but unless SE wants to buy this from me for a million dollars I don't see why it shouldn't be zlib or something similar.

#### Download

Live here: https://captainzidgel.github.io/stackdeck/

#### Platform

All browsers that support the latest JavaScript.

### Contact

Made by me, Captain Zidgel / Allister. If you have to contact me... I don't know, @ me or something on a question comment.

### Code

Written in HTML, JS, Vue.js

https://github.com/captainzidgel/stackdeck

### Conclusion

I hope you find Stackdeck useful. I certainly learned a lot making it, which was my intention.

Comment: It's fine to publicize your key, the app page says "This is not considered a secret, and may be safely embed in client side code or distributed binaries."

Comment: The thing that's private is any token your app gets for the user. Tokens can be obtained through the OAuth2 flow and allow that instance of your app to get information that is private to the user, or to perform actions on SE as the user. The token is private to the user, so it's OK to store one in a secure manner locally, but is not something which you should be transmitting to a server.

Comment: Oh all right that's pretty sick then, I was pulling teeth trying to figure out how to write a JS server and the app has no SE user interaction, so it will be very convenient to me just to embed the key.